# NodeJS static file HTTP server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server

I wrote a NodeJS HTTP server specifically for serving static files. I didn't bother much about security since the server is going to be used locally in my Electron application.

```
function buildStaticServer() {
    const fs = require("fs");
    const urlModule = require("url");
    return require("http").createServer(function(req, res) {
        var parsedUrl = urlModule.parse(req.url, true);
        var completePath = __dirname + parsedUrl.pathname;
        console.log(completePath);
        fs.stat(completePath, function(err, statObj){
            //we first check if the pathName exists
            if(err){
                res.writeHead(404);
                return res.end("404 Directory not found");
            }
            if(statObj.isDirectory()){
                //if the pathname is a directory, we're gonna try to send the index.html in that directory
                fs.readFile(completePath + "/index.html", function(err, data){
                    if(err){
                        res.writeHead(404);
                        return res.end("404 File Corrupt or Not Found");
                    }
                    res.writeHead(200);
                    res.write(data);
                    return res.end();                   
                })
            }
            fs.readFile(completePath, function(err, data){
                if(err){
                    res.writeHead(404);
                    res.end("404 File Corrupt or Not Found");
                    return;
                }
                res.writeHead(200);
                res.write(data);
                return res.end();
            })
        }); 
    });
}
var staticServer = buildStaticServer().listen(9000);
```

Comment: You could just import express. http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-static-content

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @PatrickS I didn't wanna use express here since I am developing an Electron app and I feel like it's too heavy for a simple static file server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are more efficient ways to do this. Now you are buffering the whole file content into memory, when you perform `fs.readFile(...)`. I recommend that you use a `readStream`, that for example using `fs.createReadStream(<path>)`, pipe it into `res`. This way you will begin sending the file content earlier, and stop wasting your node processes memory. Also consider moving `require` to the top of your code, it is a bad practice to call `require` from function body.